# SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus') equating to 1 even if Always On is not configured

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, high-availability

We have a SQL Server Enterprise 2017. I would like to get insights as to why our `SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus')`returns 1 even if Always On is not configured in this instance.

I have a local instance in my work machine that is a stand alone. When I run `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus')` it returns `1` even if I have not set up Always On on this machine. Never have attempted to check the "Enable Always ON" box on the Service in the SQL server Configuration Manager.

I have setup this instance to be a publisher and a distributor for Replication. I have restored databases on this instance that the database were part of the availability databases.

I guess my question is, how does this `SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus')` evaluates? What conditions does it check?

Comment: Looks like this may just be a change to the default as it is set to 1 on my servers and I haven't changed it.

Comment: @TonyHinkle You dont have Always On setup on your instance as well? What do you mean change to the default?

Comment: No, we don't have any any 2017 clusters yet.  I'm suggesting that the default value for 2012-2016 was 0, and the default for for 2017 is 1.

Comment: You should check `IsHadrEnabled` and not HadrManagerStatus.  to see if AlwaysON feature is enabled or not.

Comment: Think of `HadrManagerStatus` as the gateway to `IsHadrEnabled`. The former is just what makes the latter (and Availability Groups) possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by [Kin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/8783/kin-shah), if you want to check on whether the "Enable Always On" checkbox is checked in SQL Server Configuration Manager, you should be using this property instead:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled');
```

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on `IsHadrEnabled`:

> Always On availability groups is enabled on this server instance.

Regarding the other setting (`HadrManagerStatus`), here's what docs has to say:

> Indicates whether the Always On availability groups manager has started.

I don't really know what the "Availability Groups manager" is, but it sounds like probably an internal component to SQL Server.

[Tony](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/63284/tony-hinkle) helpfully pointed out that this value was non-zero on non-AG instances prior to 2017.  I just verified this on a SQL Server 2016 instance where AGs are not enabled and set up, and I get "2" ("*Not started and failed*").

I'm speculating here, but the fact that the "AG manager" component is started by default on SQL Server 2017 probably has something to do with the clusterless, ["read-scale" AG feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017) introduced in that version.  So on 2017 this component is able to start up and run, whereas previous versions noticed the lack of WSFC and failed to start.

Anyway, that's just a guess.  Maybe someone from Microsoft will come by and confirm one way or the other.  The real answer is what Kin pointed out - if you want to check for AG's being enabled, use `IsHadrEnabled`.

Comment: `IsHadrEnabled` does fit for our needs. Thanks. What is weird is that I have 2 local instances in my workstation. Instance1 is the publisher and distributor for replication which returns `1` when i run the `HadrManagerStatus`. Instance2 on my machine however returns `0` when i run the query. Instance2 is basically my subscriber for my replication, and thats really all there is for my Instance2. Same machine. No failover cluster configured. Never have messed with AOAG for both.